# No se muestra la ventana de aceptar permisos en IONIC CORDOVA

Tags: ionic

Lo que intento hacer es que al momento de pulsar un botón, me aparezca la ventana para aceptar el permiso de leer archivos externos, me he dado cuenta que lo que falla es el `requestPermissions`.
Donde estoy probando es en un android 11 y no tiene los permisos aceptados.

```
  permisson(){
    alert("ejecutando")
    this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    .then( (result )=> {
        alert('checando si tiene permiso');
        alert(result.hasPermission)
        if(!result.hasPermission){
          alert("No tiene permiso")
            // este codigo no funciona
               this.androidPermissions
               .requestPermissions(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }else {
          alert("si tiene permiso")
        }
      },
      (error )=> this.androidPermissions
      .requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar solicitar el permiso desde el app.component asi cuando se inicia la aplicación pedirá los permisos la primer vez al estar aceptados cuando tu app lo requiera ya los permisos están listos para usarse con tu api o dispositivo